# Best replace for named mutexs for synchronized access per resource

Tags: c#, mutex, named

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
        // If current thread needs resource(i) then

        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Mutex" + i.ToString());
        mutex.WaitOne();

        // synchronized access to resource(i)

        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

We have 100 resources and each of them should be accessed by a single thread concurrently (it's OK to access resource[2] and resource[5] concurrently) so I used the above code. What's the best alternative for named mutexes in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all in a single process, then there's no need for named mutexs at all. Just create a list or array of N objects and use `lock`.

```
const int NumLocks = 100;
List<object> LockObjects = new List<object>(NumLocks);

// to initialize
for (int i = 0; i < NumLocks; ++i)
{
    LockObjects.Add(new object());
}

// and your loop
for (int i = 0; i < NumLocks; ++i)
{
    // if current thread needs lock[i] then
    lock(LockObjects[i])
    {
        // do whatever you need to do
        // and then release the lock
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can lock the individual resource objects. If they really are objects. I've found that using a separate lock object is easier to understand and maintain, because a "resource" might be a method or a group of objects. The lock object is an abstraction that, for me, aids in understanding.

If multiple processes need this, then I don't see a good solution other than using the `Mutex`. However, I'd suggest creating a list of those `Mutex` objects at the start of your program and keeping them around. That way, in the loop all you have to do is `WaitOne`--there's no need to create the object each time in the loop.

Comment: In fact resources don't have indexes. They have unique names so there is `resource[key]` rather than `resource(i)` then what type is suitable for using as lock ?

Comment: I would suggest using the solution I posted, with a `List<object>` for the locks. So in order to use `resource[key]`, you lock `LockObjects[key]`. If `key` isn't a sequential integer, then build a `Dictionary<keyType, object>` for the locks. As long as there's a one-to-one relationship between lock objects and resources, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming resources are instances of reference classes, simply lock each resource.

```
var r = resource(i);
lock (r)
{
    // synchronized access to resource(i)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately resources are `Lazy` objects and I prefer not awake them unnecessarily but the idea is creative.